# Script file won't execute after publishing

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, war, ironpython

I have a script in my servlet that should run. Before publishing the webapp "Exporting it to WAR file" the script runs, but after publishing it, it doesn't. 
Any clue ? I use Tomcat 8, JAVA/JSP (Backend/Frontend)
My script is a python one, it sends automated emails, this is how I call it from my servlet.

```
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            doGet(request, response);

            String[] pythonscript = new String[3] ;
            pythonscript[0] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7\\ipy64.exe";
            pythonscript[1] = "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 8.0\\webapps\\myapp\\db_monitor.py";
            pythonscript[2] = "Email:  Comment/Question: Hello ";
            File file = new File("test.log");
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file);
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pythonscript);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace(ps);
                }

        }
```

And this is the script written in Python/IronPython

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Exchange\\Web Services\\2.1\\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")
from Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data import *


def main():
    ex_service = ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010)
    ex_service.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    ex_service.AutodiscoverUrl("me@company.com", redirect_url_validation_callback)
    email = EmailMessage(ex_service)
    email.BccRecipients.Add("me@company.com");      


    email.Subject = "New Report / Test "
    email.Body = '''A new report has been published'''
    email.Send()

def redirect_url_validation_callback(redirect_url):
    redirect_uri = Uri(redirect_url)
    return redirect_uri.Scheme == "https"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Do I need to modify the paths that I call from the servlet? They are correct as far as I know and tested but when I publish that webapp, the script won't run...

UPDATE: After logging output, I found what errors I was getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\myapp\db_monitor.py", line 26, in <module>

  File "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\myapp\db_monitor.py", line 19, in main

Exception: SendOnly cannot be used by a user without a mailbox.  Use SendAndSaveCopy and specify a folder ID in a mailbox to send an item from an account that doesn't have a mailbox.
```

Comment: There are many reasons why something that works in your IDE or commandline does not work after it's deployed. To find the specific reason why it doesn't work for you, you're going to have to be a bit more specific, otherwise we'll just be guessing. Like, it could be that your database configuration doesn't apply on the  server environment, or, a file in your IDE that's not published. Could you tell us more about what this "script" is and how you run it? Are there any errormessages or relevant log entries? [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more tips.

Comment: @Kenney Thank you for the notes, I have added more details, please check again.

Comment: Thank you, that's useful. Are you deploying on the same machine that you are developing on (localhost)? Do you get any output from that `e.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: Yes I'm deploying on the same machine (localhost). Where can I check for any output coming from the exception? When I'm not deploying the script gets executed with no issues, only when I publish it stops working..

Comment: There is probably a log file in your webserver. You could also rethrow that exception as a [`ServletException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletException.html) to have the webserver show an error page instead of what I imagine might be a blank screen? How exactly do you test that the script gets executed, both when you're not deploying, and when you have published it? What results do you get when it works, and when it doesn't?

Comment: I re-threw the exception into a file and it is blank :/
How I tested it, before deploying I simply created a tomcat server in eclipse and added the web application to it and ran it, and it worked and I mean by worked that I received an email as desired. Once I published it, I won't receive any kind of email and the exception file I created is empty ...

Comment: @Kenney do I need to modify the paths even though they are correct 100%? I mean, does WAR files require some modifications on the way we write the Path ?

Comment: Your program does not check for failure, Something is going wrong somewhere, so to find the cause, we need to trace your program. Get some logging going - sending text back to the client, appending a file - whatever. It should at least tell you that something went right: writing a log message. [`Runtime.exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) returns a `Process` - does it say anything about whether the python script executed normally, whether there is something on `stderr`?

Comment: Any error in `catalina.out`?

Comment: No nothing @DavidLevesque.

Comment: @Kenney Do you suggest that I store the output of the command ?

Comment: Replace `e.printStackTrace(ps)` by `e.printStackTrace()`, deploy, run and look in `catalina.out` again. You should see some stack trace.

Comment: @WT86 Add a `ps.print("Hello World");` as early as possible and see if you see that appear in "test.log". Btw, what does `doGet()` do? Could you comment it out just to test whether the problem is in the code you posted?

Comment: @Kenney I have done that and it prints, that is really confusing. Is there any option to enable shell commands in tomcat under web.xml or any other config file ?

Comment: Not that I know of; there could be a SecurityManager policy but you'd get an error. Add some more log entries to see what is happening: for instance `ps.println( "exec() return code: " . Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pythonscript).waitFor() );`. It should log `exec() return code: 0` if the python script is successfully executed.

Comment: @Kenney while running the web application through eclipse it's giving me 0 but when I'm publishing it "export to WAR" it is giving me 1 ....

Comment: Allright, the Java part is okay, but there's a problem running the python script. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` returns a [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html); save the `Process`, and read the `getOutputStream()` and `getErrorStream()` to see what the script outputs.

Comment: @Kenney would you kindly check the error I got ? I just updated the question

Comment: Ah, now you're getting somewhere! Unfortunately I've little to no experience with Exchange, but at last you got a clear error message. Perhaps [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767176/microsoft-exchange-webservices-data-serviceresponseexception-connection-did-not) helps? Good luck!

Comment: I was looking at it... Thank you so much for helping me out :)